# Why JSF needs XHTML instead of HTML?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml

All JSF Code-Example i have seen befor have used XHTML. But why?
Why i can not use HTML instead of XHTML?

For me XHTML (with all the namespaces and namespaces-tags) looks a lot less clear than normal HTML.

Comment: jsf has to be well-formed xml-documents that is why they are written xhtml. in html5 with jsf 2.2 you just import the xml namespace

Comment: "less clear" is in the eye of the beholder. I like that it's easy to see in the source which tag names belong to native html and which sections are of the various JSF modules.

Comment: XHTML is used for the "X" part of it: eXtensible. JSF makes use of a lot of constructs that HTML will not cater for

Comment: XHTML was astonishingly overhyped a decade ago. Lot of starters (particularly those from PHP world) completely fail to see/understand that XHTML is intented to be used as a templating language to generate HTML. Please don't get mislead by this ridiculous overhype. For more detail, see the duplicate and the XHTML wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info (which you can get by clicking the "info" link in the black popbox when you hover the `[xhtml]` tag below the question).